# Android Scrollview thumview change

Tags: android, android-scrollbar

in application listview i had more than 1000 data in listview and its tedious to scroll. i try to change scroll thume but cannot change.i requre scroll thum like below image

```
<ListView
 android:id="@+id/listview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_below="@+id/layoutProduct"
 android:background="#00000000"
 android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
 android:dividerHeight="1dp"
 android:fadeScrollbars="true"
 android:fadingEdge="none"
 android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
 android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/a_apptheme_fastscroll_thumb_holo"
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
 android:listSelector="#00000000"
 android:scrollingCache="false" >
 </ListView>
```

[image: Thum Image]

User can drag scrol thume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `setFastScrollEnabled(true);` method on your ListView. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollEnabled(boolean)

Comment: thanks it working in latest api it's looks diffrent but the thing exact i want that got

Comment: You can change the the Drawable with a style.. If I remember correctly.

Comment: like this android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/a_apptheme_fastscroll_thumb_holo"?

Comment: Add `android:fastScrollThumbDrawable` to you theme.

Answer (score 0):

In your ListView XML definition, add

```
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
```

Create file fastscroll_thumb.xml in the res/drawable folder as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll_pressed" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll" />
</selector>
```

Create a values folder in the res folder. Create themes.xml files in res/values as follows:

```
<resources>
  <style name="ApplicationTheme">
      <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```